# Get Facebook Page Wall Stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I want to get the posts (only from the band, not others) from a Facebook Page Wall (its a Band, so no private profile) and publish it on *MY* own site.

I hoped to get the Posts as XML or JSON and then parse them.
So I wanted to use Facebook as a news System.

But I didn't find a solution - I don't want to have the user to log in with his account to see anything - it should be just a public stream.

The only idea I found was to use twitter as an export mechanism, but that's kind of elaborate.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Facebook php sdk:  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk
It ends up looking like this:

```
//
include('facebook.php');
$fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => $yourAppId,
        'secret' => $yourSecret,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($fb_config);
$feed = $facebook->api("/{$nameOfFaceBookPage}/feed");
```

That will give you an array of feed stories.

Comment: It gives following error
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {eyuvadotcom} thrown in C:\wamp\www\fbpage\src\base_facebook.php on line 1254


sorry it worked. i forgot to remove {}
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I assume you created a facebook page for your band and it has url in such format:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/<band_name>/<page_id>
```

In this case you can read wall posts in json format using Graph API (no login required):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed
```

Comment: Is there a way to style the JSON output exactly as it appears in Facebook? And attach interactions (Like, Comment) to each post?

Comment: To answer Doublethink's question yes there is.. Store the Josn Values (ex. $user->name) into (ex. $name = $user->name;) then design your format around that info.

Comment: I just tried what Serg said via The Facebook Page for USO Fort Carson https://graph.facebook.com/160957710611220/feed and I get: An access token is required to request this resource. from Facebook so Thanks for voting down my edit.

Comment: Use an access token then; if there's no demographic restrictions on the page any access token (user, page or app) will work - if there are restrictions you need to use a user access token for a user that meets the restrictions

Answer (score 1):

If you only want posts from "me", can't you just use the Like Box social plugin and show the stream? This plugin will only show posts from the page owner.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a similar app and after a lot of searching finally accomplished

https://graph.facebook.com/194466683916784/feed?access_token=AAACTzPZAxblQBAHND7fo1rA58VqQawuJb806Q6BeIFhTroyGSYIe5i0R5fZAZBtffNvkkZB7ayvV7Vw7j7ZBf7vGt6xHx2gjx4FhO8d27sAZDZD

enter your page wall id after .com and in the access token get your own access token from Graph - API explorer

Then exchange that token for a longer for a longer lived one that is for 60 days and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had your same problem and I was looking for something very simple to publish feeds of facebook pages, but I didn’t find any solution on the web.

What I want to achieve are the post (only from my personal fan page, not the other) of the bulletin board (facebook wall) of a FB page (this is a fan page, not private profiles) and publish it on my site.

I was hoping to get the posts in JSON or XML format and then encode them so as to use FB as a news system. Unfortunately I haven’t found any kind of solution because I don’t want the user has to log in his account to see something so it must be a flow of pubblic feed.

So, I decided to code the plugin. Here the link to the tutorial:
http://www.lorenzodedonato.com/freebies/facebook-plugin-per-visualizzare-i-post-della-bacheca-di-una-pagina-fan-creato-in-php-json/